# Sequelize: Not all values in forEach get inserted to SQLite DB

Tags: node.js, json, sequelize.js

I have an sqlite DB which i want to populate with 137k entries which are retrieved from multiple API calls.
There are only about 6k entries in my sqlite db, but if I export the lines into a text file, in the text file is the correct amount of 137k lines.

Here is the code for inserting into the database and appending to the text file.
Here is my index.js

```
const db = require("./config/database");
const items = require("./models/items");
var fs = require('fs');
const baseURL = 'xxx';
const namespace = 'static-eu';
const region = 'eu';
const client = 'xxx';
const secret = 'xxx';
const tokenURL = 'xxx';



const getToken = async function(client, secret)
{
    const body = "grant_type=client_credentials";
    const response = await fetch(tokenURL, {
        method: 'post',
        body: body,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(client + ':' + secret).toString('base64')}
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    const jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
    const json = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    return json['access_token'];
}
const getItems = async function(ID)
{
    const access_token =  await getToken(client, secret);
    const reqURL = baseURL + '/data/wow/search/item?namespace=' + namespace + '&_pageSize=1000&orderby=id&id=['+ ID + ',]&access_token=' + access_token;
    const response = await fetch(reqURL, {
        method: 'get',
        //headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    const jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
    const json = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    var arrayID = [];
    json.results.forEach(function (item, index){
           try {
               items.upsert({
                   itemID: json.results[index].data.id,
                   desc_de: json.results[index].data.name.de_DE,
                   desc_en: json.results[index].data.name.en_US,
                   media: json.results[index].data.id,
                   item_class_de: json.results[index].data.item_class.name.de_DE,
                   item_class_en: json.results[index].data.item_class.name.en_US,
               });
           }
           catch (error) {
               return console.log(error.name + error.message);
           }
        arrayID.push(json.results[index].data.id);
        });

    const nextID = (Math.max(...arrayID)) + 1;
    return nextID;


    //Object.keys(json.results[data]).forEach(function(results){
     //   console.log('Key : ' + results + ', Value : ' + json["id"])
    //    })
}
const getAll = async function()
{
    let ID = 1;
    while(1==1)
    {
        console.log(ID);
        ID = await getItems(ID);
}};

db.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Logged in to DB!');
        items.init(db);
        items.sync();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
getAll();
```

my items.js

```
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = class items extends Model {
    static init(sequelize){
        return super.init({
            itemID: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true
            },
            desc_de: DataTypes.STRING,
            desc_en: DataTypes.STRING,
            media: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            item_class_de: DataTypes.STRING,
            item_class_en: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, {
            tableName: 'items',
            timestamps: true,
            sequelize
        });
    }
}
```

my database.js

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: './data/items.sqlite',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More context would be required for this one.

What you could do is check if `items.upsert()` returns any errors.

Add a try-catch block to check for any issues.

Use a loop instead to insert the data into batches. It definitely improves performance, a good library is `async` or `bluebird`

Check your db schema if it can handle 137k entries.

Edit: Read these updated codes out and see how it fits in your requirements

getAll()

```
const pQueue = require('p-queue');
const queue = new pQueue({ concurrency: 5 });

const getAll = async function() {
    let ID = 1;
    while (true) {
        console.log(ID);
        const nextID = await queue.add(() => getItems(ID));
        if (!nextID) {
            break;
        }
        ID = nextID;
    }
};
```

getItems()

```
const getItems = async function(ID) {
    const access_token = await getToken(client, secret);
    const reqURL =
        baseURL +
        '/data/wow/search/item?namespace=' +
        namespace +
        '&_pageSize=1000&orderby=id&id=[' +
        ID +
        ',]&access_token=' +
        access_token;
    const response = await fetch(reqURL, {
        method: 'get',
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    const jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
    const json = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    var arrayID = [];
    json.results.forEach(function(item, index) {
        try {
            items.upsert({
                itemID: json.results[index].data.id,
                desc_de: json.results[index].data.name.de_DE,
                desc_en: json.results[index].data.name.en_US,
                media: json.results[index].data.id,
                item_class_de: json.results[index].data.item_class.name.de_DE,
                item_class_en: json.results[index].data.item_class.name.en_US,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return console.log(error.name + error.message);
        }
        arrayID.push(json.results[index].data.id);
    });

    if (!json.hasOwnProperty('next_page')) {
        return false;
    }

    const nextID = Math.max(...arrayID) + 1;
    return nextID;
};
```

Alternate version with transactions

```
const getItems = async function(ID) {
    const access_token = await getToken(client, secret);
    const reqURL =
        baseURL +
        '/data/wow/search/item?namespace=' +
        namespace +
        '&_pageSize=1000&orderby=id&id=[' +
        ID +
        ',]&access_token=' +
        access_token;
    const response = await fetch(reqURL, {
        method: 'get',
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    const jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
    const json = JSON.parse(jsondata);
    var arrayID = [];
    const itemsData = json.results.map(function(item) {
        return {
            itemID: item.data.id,
            desc_de: item.data.name.de_DE,
            desc_en: item.data.name.en_US,
            media: item.data.id,
            item_class_de: item.data.item_class.name.de_DE,
            item_class_en: item.data.item_class.name.en_US,
        };
    });

    return db.transaction(async (transaction) => {
        await items.bulkCreate(itemsData, { transaction });
    }).then(() => {
        arrayID = json.results.map(function(item) {
            return item.data.id;
        });

        if (!json.hasOwnProperty('next_page')) {
            return false;
        }

        const nextID = Math.max(...arrayID) + 1;
        return nextID;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried with a try-catch block, but it didn't throw any errors. I am already looping over the 137k entries, by only inserting 1k at a time.
I added all of my code for more context.

Comment: I can see you are making too many API calls in a short amount of time. You could be getting rate limited or throttled by the API provider. Add a delay between the calls or use `p-queue` library to limit concurrent calls.

Comment: Also it's only waiting on one API call to complete before starting the next, which is bad.

Comment: There also might be an infinite looping here, your code does not seem to check if there are more pages of items available in the API response. Could you take a look at that? I think the response should have a `next_page` property or something similar.

Comment: If I would get rate limited, I wouldnt be able to write all 137k lines into my text file, right? So I think that is not the issue. The API allows 36000 calls per hour

Comment: I have added some reference above with how the code would look like with the p-queue and stuff. check it out.

Comment: Another solution would be using transactions for db inserts if you are familiar with it

Comment: p-queue doesnt work for me somehow.
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported.

Comment: I will give transactions a shot, maybe thats helping, thank you

Comment: @ChristophRitzer No worries, I have added piece of code on how transaction would fit in your code, in the above answer. Just adapt to your own as appropriate and debug if you see any errors. To install `p-queue`, use `npm install p-queue --save`

Comment: I did install p-queue before, but somehow I got the error, that I have to use "import" instead of "require".
But doesn't matter - it worked with your transaction/bulkcreate example. I had to remove the check for the "next_page" property, because there is no value like that. It always takes the last ID, and then gets the next 1000 Items starting from the last ID.
Thanks for your help, its all good now

Comment: @ChristophRitzer Glad to hear, transaction is always a great option in most use case as it also helps with reverting queries if something fails as a plus. Could you press the tick on the left side of my answer and mark this thread as answered?